# How would one decorate an inherited method in the child class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

I'm not quite sure how to use a decorator on an inherited method. Normally decorators are put before the definition but for an inherited function the definition is given in the parent and not the child class. I would like to avoid rewriting the definition of the method in the child class and simply specify to put the decorator around the inherited method.

To make myself clearer, here is a working example of what I mean:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def gets_drink(cls, ):
        print "it's time to get a drink!"
        return "A beer"

def dec(some_f):
    def legal_issue(obj,):
        some_f(obj)
        return 'A Coke'
    return legal_issue

class Child(Person):
    def __init__(self, age):
        Person.__init__(self, age=age)

    #in principle i'd like to write
    #@dec
    #self.gets_drink
    #which does not work
    #the only working way I found is by defining the method as a classmethod
    #and write this:

    @dec
    def gets_drink(self, ):
        return Person.gets_drink()

dad = Person(42)
son = Child(12)

print dad.gets_drink()
print son.gets_drink()
```

The way it is done in this example works, but it looks somehow weird to me, replacing the method with a call to the original method only to be able to put the decorator. Also, for this to work, the method needs to be defined as a classmethod in the parent class.

Am I missing something? How would experienced developers do this?

Any help, insights, critical comments and free coffees are much appreciated!

Comment: I am not following you here. Why did you replace `gets_drink` with a call to the original?

Comment: You mean you want to know if using a decorator is a better way to augment an inherited method than to use `super()` to call the original?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: initially I wanted to modify some of the arguments for objects of the child class and as far as I know, this can be easily done with a decorator.

Comment: I am not really seeing it; you can easily give the new override method a different signature. You don't *have* to use the same arguments as the overridden method of the parent class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes I know. And I'm well aware that this dummy example up there would look nicer if I'd simply overwrite the method. But the question is a more general one, decorators are useful and suppose for the parent class our method does not need a decorator, but for the child class it does. In this case I'd go for a solution looking somehow like the example. Would you do it differently?

Comment: Absolutely; de decorator function would live outside the class body, for example.

Comment: Is it a problem to put it inside the class like this? For me this does not seem particularly unnatural.

Comment: It is now a (broken) method on your class. Sure, the name starts with a `_` *but it isn't a method*. Moreover, it isn't the place where experienced Python devs would look for the definition of the decorator, it certainly surprised me as I was looking for a standalone function instead.

Comment: I get it, it lacks a positional argument, right? Hm, so the approach to take is to define the decorator function outside the class body.

Comment: I cannot see though why python happily _breaks_ the method without raising any exceptions.

Comment: Python didn't break it, you did by putting in a function that cannot be used as a method.

Comment: There is no exception to throw, not until you try to use it as a method. Welcome to a dynamic language!

Comment: Changed the example: the decorator function lives outside the class now. But even if the decorator lives outside the class body (which is certainly how this should be done), the gets_drink method still needs to be decorated. Is in the example not how this should be done?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Edited the question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, thank you, now your issue is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't *have* to use a decorator in decorator syntax. It is just a callable:

```
class Child(Person):
    def __init__(self, age):
        Person.__init__(self, age=age)

    gets_drink = dec(Person.gets_drink.__func__)
```

This adds the return value of the decorator to the child class as a method with the same name. The `__func__` attribute unwraps the bound (class) method, retrieving the original function.

Note that your new method is now a regular method, not a classmethod, you'd have to re-wrap the result in a `classmethod()` call for that.

This works because the syntax

```
@decorator_expression
def function_definition():
    pass
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
def function_definition():
    pass
function_definition = decorator_expression(function_definition)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer! Well in the example the method is defined as a classmethod just to make it work - it does not need to be a class method. In fact, if `gets_drink` is not a classmethod, then the `__func__` should also not be needed.

Comment: @jojo: In Python 2 you'd still want to use `__func__` as a unbound method object is returned. Unwrapping avoids adding an unnecessary reference to the parent class and layering. In Python 3, accessing the function on the class returns just the function.

Comment: But I'm still wondering, is how I did in the example a bad approach?

Comment: @jojo: **If** you want to apply a decorator to an inherited method in a subclass, what I did is the better approach.

Comment: @MarijnPieters: Totally agree with you that your approach looks better. But this is not what I'm still wondering about. I'm wondering if how it is done in the example is an approach to avoid and if so why.

Comment: @jojo: You already answered that; you have to create an 'empty' body that just calls the original version.